# How to set width of the flutter togglebuttons widget

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout, hybrid-mobile-app

I have tried nesting togglebuttons inside container and giving it a custom width however it didn't worked

```
ToggleButtons(
            borderColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent[100],
            fillColor: Colors.deepOrange[100],
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            selectedBorderColor: Colors.deepOrange,

            children: <Widget>[
              new Row(children: <Widget>[new Icon(Icons.whatshot,size: 16.0,color: Colors.red,),new SizedBox(width: 4.0,), new Text("HOT",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),)],),
              new Row(children: <Widget>[new Icon(Icons.invert_colors,size: 16.0,color: Colors.yellow[800],),new SizedBox(width: 4.0,), new Text("WARM",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow[800]))],),
              new Row(children: <Widget>[new Icon(Icons.ac_unit,size: 16.0,color: Colors.blue,),new SizedBox(width: 4.0,), new Text("COLD",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue))],),
            ],
            onPressed: (int index) {
              setState(() {
                EnquiryModel.instance.setStatus(index.toString());
                for (int buttonIndex = 0; buttonIndex < isSelected.length; buttonIndex++) {
                  if (buttonIndex == index) {
                    isSelected[buttonIndex] = true;
                  } else {
                    isSelected[buttonIndex] = false;
                  }
                }
              });
            },
            isSelected: isSelected,
          )
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I know my answer is not good solution but it works.

```
children: <Widget>[
    Container(width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 36)/3, child: new Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: <Widget>[new Icon(Icons.whatshot,size: 16.0,color: Colors.red,),new SizedBox(width: 4.0,), new Text("HOT",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),)],)),
    Container(width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 36)/3, child: new Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: <Widget>[new Icon(Icons.invert_colors,size: 16.0,color: Colors.yellow[800],),new SizedBox(width: 4.0,), new Text("WARM",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow[800]))],)),
    Container(width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 36)/3, child: new Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: <Widget>[new Icon(Icons.ac_unit,size: 16.0,color: Colors.blue,),new SizedBox(width: 4.0,), new Text("COLD",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue))],)),
]
```

I decrease 36 because my page has page padding. You can change it with your settings.

Here result:

[image: ToggleButtons Result]

Answer (score 4):

To set the width dynamically to the parent widget you can use a LayoutBuilder. In the attached link you'll find a cleaner solution.

[Expand toggle buttons to parent container width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60456821/expand-toggle-buttons-to-parent-container-width)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `Container`, use `BoxConstraints`.

```
ToggleButtons(
    children: <Widget>[
        Row(children: <Widget>[Icon(Icons.whatshot, size: 16.0, color: Colors.red), SizedBox(width: 4.0), Text('HOT', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red))]),
        Row(children: <Widget>[Icon(Icons.invert_colors, size: 16.0, color: Colors.yellow[800]), SizedBox(width: 4.0), Text('WARM', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow[800]))]),
        Row(children: <Widget>[Icon(Icons.ac_unit, size: 16.0, color: Colors.blue), SizedBox(width: 4.0), Text('COLD', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue))]),
    ],
    constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 36) / 3),
    isSelected: isSelected,
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The Eyupaltindal answer worked for me only in Flutter beta version (I'm using v1.12.13+hotfix.3), on Flutter last release version 1.9.1 I'm not able to change ToggleButtons's children padding or size. Probably in the next Flutter release it will be possible.

P.S.: Sorry I'm leaving this comment as an answer, is just because I don't have the needed reputation level to make comments.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote such a function to calculate the width

```
  double _buttonWidth(BuildContext context) {
final maxWidth = 120.0;
final buttonCount = 3;

final width = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 100) / buttonCount;
if (width < maxWidth) {
  return width;
} else {
  return maxWidth;
}
```

}

Usage:

```
  ToggleButtons(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        width: _buttonWidth(context),
        child: Text('Yes'),
      ),
      Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        width: _buttonWidth(context),
        child: Text('No'),
      ),
      Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        width: _buttonWidth(context),
        child: Text('I dont know'),
      ),
    ],
    onPressed: (int index) {},
    isSelected: [false, true, false],
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

A clean way is to utilize `BoxConstraints` property for `ToggleButtons`.

To achieve **square buttons** that fit in the screen:

```dart
    // get your children to be displayed. Use 1 to compensate empty list case.
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9 / max(1, children.length);

    return ToggleButtons(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: width, minWidth: width, minHeight: width, maxHeight: width),
      children: children,
      isSelected: selections,
    );
```

Calling `minWidth` and `maxWidth` with exact value will force Flutter to render item with the desired width. Same for `minHeight` and `maxHeight`.

If you don't want squared buttons, you can play with setting other value (the same) for `minHeight` and `maxHeight`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to my experience is to use **Sizedbox**. If you want the same size, you don't need to devide it, for example from your case: 3. Because the width is *automatically divided*, with the same size:

**1. First solution:**

> ```
> SizedBox(
>   width: double.infinity,
>   child: YourToggleButtons,
> )
> ```

**2. Second solution:**

> ```
> SizedBox.expand(
>   child: new YourToggleButtons,
> )
> ```

Have a nice day.