# Expand toggle buttons to parent container width

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to **dynamically** expand toggle buttons to parent container width without hard coding anything. I found one answer to that which uses MediaQuery of context which only works well for full screen width. I also tried to wrap the buttons in expanded widget but that throws an error

```
Container(
  width: 150.0, // hardcoded for testing purpose 
  child: ToggleButtons(
    constraints:
        BoxConstraints.expand(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width), // this doesn't work once inside container unless hard coding it
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
    children: [
      ShapeToggleButton(
        text: 'Option1',
      ),
      ShapeToggleButton(
        text: 'Option2',
      ),
    ],
    isSelected: [true, false],
    onPressed: (index) {},
  ),
);
```

Comment: Try `BoxConstraints.expand()`. (Leave parameters out.)

Comment: Abion47 That throws an error --- BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.

Comment: i am not sure if i get you right: suppose you have one big parent container and 2 toggle buttons, so you would like then to fill entire container - one button on the left half and one on the right half?

Comment: pskink yes... basically stretch them (dynamically) so the two (or whatever is needed) buttons takes the whole width of the parent container

Comment: `child: LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) {
    return ToggleButtons(
      children: [
        Container(width: constraints.maxWidth / 2 - 1.5, alignment: Alignment.center, child: Text('Option1',)),
        Container(width: constraints.maxWidth / 2 - 1.5, alignment: Alignment.center, child: Text('Option2',)),
      ],
      isSelected: [true, false],
      onPressed: (index) {},
    );
  }
),` - as you can see its fighting against the system, but if you are anarchist...

Comment: Thanks pskink.. I think that would work... You can place it as an answer so I can mark this as answered

Comment: notice `1.5` magic numbers above, isn't it beautiful? but most likely good enough for a "lonely wolf fighting with the rest of the world" ;-) but seriously you would need: `width: (constraints.maxWidth - (N + 1)) / N` where `N` is number of buttons, for example 2 - of course i will not post it as an answer since it is ugly workaround that is likely not to work tomorrow or one day after ... ;-)

Comment: pskink :) Yes I already modified it to my needs. I do believe that 1.5 is width of toggle buttons borders so if I don't want a border then I can remove it from there and just use width: constraints.maxWidth / N. It works I already tried that

Comment: aha ok, good to know - i used at first `constraints.maxWidth / N` too but i had error: `width overflowed by 3 pixels` or something so thats why i used that magic

Comment: Yes it is border width... Try to add to ToggleButtons parameter renderBorder: false and you don't need to use it... I have to admit that it isn't the nicest workaround but I believe that it is definitely the only one so far so you can safely put it as an answer

Comment: oh you found `renderBorder: false` so feel free to post a self answer ;-)

Comment: No.. I can't take the credit for this... I spent a lot of time figure it out and din't come with solution so the credit is all yours :)

Comment: not at all, i was only the guy who proposed an initial idea - you finished the job - the gold / fruits / beer is yours

Comment: Ohhh.. Now we are like two lowers on the phone arguing who's gonna hang up first :D I wouldn't finish it without you so the gold is yours

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As suggested by psink in comment above answer is to wrap it in LayoutBuilder

```
        Container(
              width: 150.0, // hardcoded for testing purpose
              child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
        return ToggleButtons(
          renderBorder: false,
          constraints:
              BoxConstraints.expand(width: constraints.maxWidth / 2), //number 2 is number of toggle buttons
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          children: [
            Text(
              'Option1',
            ),
            Text(
              'Option2',
            ),
          ],
          isSelected: [true, false],
          onPressed: (index) {},
        );
      })))
```

Comment: If you are rendering the border you should also substract the weight of the border * 3 (start, middle and end, assuming you only have two children) for avoiding the overflow at the right